# Send id<MTLTexture> from ios to unity

Tags: unity, ios, plugin

I'm writing a plugin for unity, I need to send a texture from ios to unity.
There is a `UnitySendMessage` function which takes `char*` as parameter, but I didn't find a way to convert `id<MTLTexture>` to `char*`.

How can I send `id<MTLTexture>` from ios and receive it in unity?

My current code :

```
//ios side ...
_texture = CVMetalTextureGetTexture(texture);
UnitySendMessage(CALLBACK_OBJECT, CALLBACK_TEXTURE_READY,_texture);//error
//...

//unity side
private void OnTextureReady(string texture_str)
{
   IntPtr texture = new IntPtr(Int32.Parse(texture_str));
   int width = 256;
   int height = 256;
   rawImage.texture = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture(width, height, 
   TextureFormat.ARGB32, false, false, texture);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to cast string to IntPtr. char* is just pointer and any pointer(char*, void*,...) coming from native side unity treat it as IntPtr.

```
id<MTLTexture> tex = yourTexture;
char* ptr = &tex;
```

And now you have a ptr from native side

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, It doesn't fix the problem, I still have to convert void* to char*(because UnitySendMessage accept char* as the third parameter)

Comment: It's doesn't matter I changed my answer I don't understand why try cast string to IntPtr